# Retrieving plain field label

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, wtforms

Is it possible to retrieve the plain field label.

When I use something like `{{ form.field.label }}` then it includes the html label
element. 
I just want to use the pain label in some places.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the tools to test here, but I think what you may be searching for is:

```
{{ form.field.label.text }}
```

See [the relevant section from the documentation](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.3/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Label):

> `field_id` The ID of the field which this label will reference.
>   `text` The original label text passed to the field’s constructor.